# Stopping an implicit cast on operator delete

Tags: c++, memory-management, implicit-conversion

My String class provides an operator char* overload to allow you to pass the string to C functions.

Unfortunately a colleague of mine just inadvertently discovered a bug.

He effectively had the following code.

```
StringT str;
// Some code.
delete str;
```

Is there anyway to prevent delete from casting the string object to a char* to prevent future bugs like this cropping up?  `std::string` gets round this problem by not providing a char operator overload but, ideally, I'd like to keep the overload but prevent that delete from working.

Comment: Yeah - Don't `delete` things that aren't pointers. Why do you care about preventing people from doing things they shouldn't be doing in the first place?

Comment: Not only this, but also don't `delete` things that are not pointers to `new`ed objects.

Comment: @Chris: If this was an argument, we wouldn't need any syntax check at all. (Very likely the code was changed from using C strings to a string class and the implicit conversion operator was introduced to ease the conversion. And that's why the `delete str;` is still in the code: the compiler didn't flag it as a syntax error.)

Comment: @sbi - It _is_ an argument. Simply dismissing it doesn't make it any less of an argument. I understand why `delete str;` works here, but the OP is asking "How do I prevent people from being stupid?" and the answer is "You can't." You can either give people an exceedingly narrow definition of what they can and can't do, or you can give people enough rope to hang themselves and see if they can't manage to make a rope bridge out of it anyway. Using C++ is already saying "I can do my own memory management!" so I don't see the need to be so strict with the rope.

Comment: @Chris: If that code is old and was indeed transitioned from C to C++ strings, then it's understandable that a `delete str;` is still in there. And from that the natural question arises of how to make the compiler complain. See Scott Meyers' article that you should make interfaces easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly. If he has a point there, then simply saying if someone writes such stupid code they deserve to get bitten falls short. For one, nobody wrote the code that attempts to delete a class object and, second, there are ways to make the compiler complain about incorrect use.

Comment: @sbi - If it was old code, then it will soon be fixed. In new code (which is going to be most of the code, since this is a new class and they're presumably mostly done backporting it) `delete str;` should never be a problem. Scott Meyers may be a smart guy, but I can still disagree. I think interfaces should just be easy to use. If that makes them easy to abuse, then I propose treating the programmer as an intelligent person capable of writing sane code. (And if the abuse is this minor, I don't see why it's such a big deal.)

Comment: @Chris: I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree then.

Comment: The way I look at it, the sole purpose of compile-time types is to prevent people from doing stupid things of this kind. In this case, the object `str` doesn't support the delete operation, and yet the expression `delete str` compiles. This is obviously a flaw in the type `StringT`, and the remaining question is whether it's an acceptable cost of the convenient char* conversion. It's not at all the same as stupid things in which the types are correct but the values are wrong, such as deleting a pointer that wasn't from `new`.

Comment: ... For a further example, adding 2 to a `new` ed pointer is invalid, but not a type error (because for some pointers, adding 2 is fine). So the language permits it. If adding *any* integer to a pointer were invalid, then the language should not (and would not) support that addition operator at all. Chris' argument seems to me to say that strong typing is useless, programmers just shouldn't make errors of type. That's a reasonable argument in general (there are plenty of untyped languages), but not a very helpful approach to C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Provide TWO implicit casts, by declaring (but not defining!)  `operator char const volatile*`. When you're passing your `StringT` to a C string function, overload resolution will still select your original `operator char const*` (exact match). But `delete str;` now becomes ambiguous.

The declaration can be private, so if it would somehow be selected will be a compile-time error. The intended ambiguity occurs before overload resolution - the `private` only serves to catch the exceedingly rare cases where the `volatile` overload would be selected somehow.

Comment: This is indeed very clever. (+1) But it might open a whole other can of worms instead of closing the other one...

Comment: There are only 2 possible extra outcomes, really: either a situation becomes ambiguous (like the `delete` case), or the `volatile` overload is now selected. The latter can only happen in a conversion sequence that ends in a `volatile` pointer. That's exceedingly rare, and it would again be an error.

Comment: @MSalters: I'd fully agree, except that passing class objects to `delete` should be exceedingly rare, too. Also, while these unwanted conversions now won't happen with `delete` anymore, they might come up in other contexts, where the overload resolution isn't ambiguous, but isn't wanted either. There's many good reasons that implicit conversions are discouraged.

Comment: Sorry, but I expanded the text to explicitly show why it is a bougs argument. But I cannot fully prove the _absence_ of such situations; you can give one concrete counterexample however.

Comment: Wait, did you just ask for an example for implicit casts doing something unintended?

Comment: Not in general, but as a result of adding this specific conversion.  So please show _sane_ code that breaks by adding the proposed `volatile` operator.

Comment: @MSalters: I don't need to, since I regretted that your trick didn't eliminate `operator const char*`. That alone leaves lots of room for unwanted conversion. As for `operator const volatile char*` - I didn't claim I knew sane code which would break it, I only pointed out that, with the same certainty, probably everybody assumed `delete obj` to be insane code that wouldn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there anyway to prevent delete from casting the string object to a char* ...?

Yep: Shy away from implicit casting operators. That's been preached for at least a decade now. Believe in it and you will lead a happier life.

Comment: Well yeah I got that ;)  I was just hoping there was some way to prevent the compiler automagically doing it in certain cases.  I'm guessing probably not .. but always worth an ask ...

Comment: I think C++1x will allow you to stick an `explicit` in front of such operators in order to prevent implicit conversions. But, frankly, I don't see the advantage of `static_cast<const char*>(str)` over `str._c_str()`.

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not, there is a reason std::string doesn't provide an implicit conversion, the c_str() function wasn't created just to irritate you. Provide implicit conversions and you open yourself up to a world of ambiguity and pain.

Answer (score 0):

**Controversial opinion time:** If someone writes code that suffers from this "bug," *they deserve to get bitten*.

To paraphrase your question:

> How do I keep people from using my firearms to shoot themselves in the foot?

You can't. I'll disagree with [@sbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138460/stopping-an-implicit-cast-on-operator-delete/2138481#2138481)'s opinion and say that *your overload is fine*. If this causes problems in someone's code, it's because someone doesn't know C++ and shouldn't be coding it.

You have bigger problems to worry about than whether or not someone who doesn't understand the language well enough to know not to `delete` things that aren't pointers can abuse your class.

Caveat: I am relatively new to C++, and have not seen the horrors of some more grizzled veterans. It is possible that a sample of particularly bad ambiguity might convince me of my evil ways. This, however, is not it.

Comment: I beg to differ. While you cannot prevent people using firearms from shooting themselves in the foot, you can minimize the number of accidents. Any army has regulations for the use of firearms to do exactly this. See the rule to not to use implicit conversions as such a regulation. Stick to it and you will eliminate a few casualties.

Comment: Particularly bad example: `struct Foo { char *x; char getX() { return *x; } char operator*() { return *0; } /* other functions */ };`. Documentation says "Foo is a smart pointer, but don't ever dereference it, use `getX` instead". This is a "valid" class, it can be used correctly, but it's a poor interface. It's perfectly reasonable to want to improve the interface, by getting rid of the "trap" laid by having an `operator*` which compiles but doesn't run. Conversion operators are difficult precisely because they create such traps via implicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Dummy {};
class StringT {
public:
    // ........
    operator char*() { /*...*/ }
    operator const char*() const { /*...*/ }

    operator const Dummy* () const { return 0; }
    operator Dummy* () { return 0; }
};

/// ...
void g(const char * ) { /*...*/ }

int main() {

    StringT str;
    g(str); // OK
    delete str; //error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'StringT' to 'void *'
    return 0;
}
```